# Trouble Configuring Common Name for Wildcard Server Block in Caddy

Tags: caddy, caddyfile

i am on a path to migrate away from nginx.
historically - we have  a *.domain.com wildcard certificate (without autorenew, letsentencrypt and others)

the caddy2 block looks like this.:

```
*.domain.com {
    tls /keys/server.crt /keys/server.key
    reverse_proxy app
}
```

it works, but some ssl clients, with strict config, moan that the CN does not match.
any chance i can set the CN to incomming host header?

my cert is fine, it works when used in nginx.

regards